# Linking to S3 file without URL - Rails - aws-sdk

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an S3 account, on which are stored videos which I need to play using an HTML5 Video element inside a rails application.

Is it possible for me to be able to load the videos into the player without making the video public and directly linking to it?

I have the gem aws-sdk and I read through the documentation and didn't find any information about this.

Excuse me? How is it unclear what I'm asking? It's not really possible to make it clearer so I guess I'll basically restate what I already said.

I need to be able to this:

`<video src="<url of file on S3>">` without making the file public in S3 so anybody can download it.

Comment: I have not used it but I think you can use a signed URL to restrict random access. [aws doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look ar presigned URLs. Use the [Presigner](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html) in the ruby sdk on the server to generate a presigned URL (for get method) for the key and insert that into the html.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article page about doing this using the aws-sdk.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html

I've only ever used Paperclip to do so.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I don't want to upload anything, I want to get and play video files that are already uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

To access private content in S3 from your rails application, there are multiple approaches available

- Create a Sign URL using Ruby AWS SDK from your Rails Backend and return the URL to the browser so that your HTML5 player can access them
- Using [AWS STS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) and [AWS Ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html) at Rails Backend, generate a temporarily access token (Which has grants to s3 bucket) and return it to the browser, where browser can use [AWS JS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) + Token to request the file

For better performance use AWS Cloufront RTMP distributions for the Videos which serves the files from S3 with [Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-how-signed-urls-work) and [Origin Access Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) limiting public access